# HTML Jinja2 disabling submit button in specific situation

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I am having problem with setting up logic for if statement in HTML template with Jinja.

What should I input in place of `???` in the below code?
I don't want the user to be able to post empty field, therefore, I have decided to disable the submit button while the textarea is empty (e.g.: it has different css style with the `form__submit__disabled` class).

I have tried inputting in the `???` place content, entry, `form__textarea`, but it doesn't work.

```html
<form class="form" action="/" method="POST">
    <p class="form__input">
        <textarea name="content" id="entry" class="form__textarea" aria-label="Entry contents" placeholder="Type here..."></textarea>
    </p>
    {% if ??? is none %}
        <button type="submit" class="form__submit__disabled" disabled>Add entry</button>
    {% else %}
        <button type="submit" class="form__submit">Add entry</button>
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

Comment: use `javascript` for that why do you even need python for that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better idea, for this requirement would be to use the [`required`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-textarea-element.html#attr-textarea-required) attribute of the `textarea`, and let the browser do the job of warning the end user that this field should be filled in before submitting.

```html
<form class="form" action="/" method="POST">
  <p class="form__input">
    <textarea name="content" 
              id="entry" 
              class="form__textarea" 
              aria-label="Entry contents" 
              placeholder="Type here..." 
              required></textarea>
  </p>
  <button type="submit" 
          class="form__submit">
    Add entry
  </button>
</form>
```